# How to map a URL address to a FQDN through CNAME dns records

Tags: dns, record

I created  a subdomain  ***sub.domain.com***. then I  issued a certificate forit. NOw, I want to add a Cname to map a URL address  Lms-traffic.manager.net.   to the full FQDN of my subdomain.
HOw should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DNS CNAME is an ALIAS for a domain name. A way to set the ip address depending on another name to get its. it does not do redirects.

the URL record is for a redirect , but will not pass any parameters, just the domain name.

You can do a redirect at the host server... httpd.conf file or .htaccess

for example. apache... SEE 
    https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

I suggest doing the redirect at the web server host, because you have a lot more control of what to pass, and where it goes to. and could do it in the .htaccess file.

Comment: if I issued an SSl cerificate for a subdomain  sub.domain.com an dwant to create a Cname DNS record,  I can go up tp the domain.   domain.com.  then add a new Cname. where     sub. will. map  th enew URL address.    I already did this,  but I still can not display the URL. address I Cnam ed.

Comment: what web server are you using ?  you must have it know about "ServerAlias" with the new name

Comment: Ok, here is. The. problem  as I am dealing with it.  I have a domain called. procloud.bh.   I created a subdomain. elearning.procloud.bh  and issued an SSL  certificate for it.   now That I created a secured website ( on Azure)
[link](https://lms-pcloudoxa-tm.trafficmanager.net)      I just want to create  A Cname dns record that let. elearning.procloud.bh.  point to  that URL address.  the url address works fine and my subdomain is fine too. BUt I mseed with records and aliases.

Comment: Issue is that for a given IP address, only a single SSH can be assigned.  HTTP1.0 does not handle domain names.  the HTTPS for that IP  address is **selearning.procloud.bh**  there are a few options.   Use a new IP address,  OR use a different Port # other than: 443   I 
IE:  https://http://lms-pcloudoxa-tm.trafficmanager.net:8443/BlaBlaBLA

Comment: is the issue that it tells you it is not secure?  or you want it to redirect to the other domain name the SSL is set up for?  or you want to have its own SSL or you want to SHARED SSL for 2 or more domain names ? OR .. Something else ?

Comment: Yes. I want. simply  redirect by  any means. ,   CNAME, Alias   my.   subdomain   elearning.prcloud.bh     to the secure. URL address.  I did  somethign rigt now. I went to the parent domain. Procloud.bh and added a Cname. that maps.  elearning. to  the URL address.  But it does not work  I mean I can pring but  when at my browser nothing is dispayed and got error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146960/discussion-between-phillip-williams-and-sam-am).